# Does notifyAll() in java release threads of other classes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering if notifyAll() in java release threads of other classes?
I mean, with this example:

```
class Friend extends Thread{}
class Enemiy extends Thread{}
```

If I do wait() in all threads (Both Friends & Enemies), and then I do:

```
// Thread Instance of a Friend
friend1.notifyAll()
```

Will it release also the Enemies instances or only the Friends one?

Comment: `notifyAll(): Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.` Which means that if you have, on your enemy, any friend object, and you call notify on it, all enemy threads that are waiting on friend will wake up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it notifies all the threads that are waitng on that object

Comment: *"that object"* been the same instance of the monitor lock under which they were synchronised when they called `wait` ;)